# Should I use prepare statement or transaction in mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is my scenario: I am setting up a game server, a bunch of insert, update, delete will be committed to database every second. I am using a prepare statement approach in php to avoid overheat of DB. (i.e. the same sql statement with different parameters will commit to the DB at the same time in every 5 second). But seems this approach is not scalable, cause if there are too many statement within one batch that the DB need to process for over 5 seconds, or even the cron job is die, there will be a critical problem.

So I am thinking of changing the prepare statement method in to transaction and commit once i receive the action from client. Will transaction in mysql helps performance like the prepare statement does? Does any one have experienced a same scenario like mine, and what is your approach? Thank you so much.

Comment: transition? May be "transaction"? Anyway, they are not actually the tools you would use to improve performance. My point it: that could affect to performance (in either good or bad way) but they aren't considered to be tools for performance improvements

Comment: Transactions do not send a lot of queries at once. It is closer to (this is an aproximation) they sending it, but making it pending. So your server needs to do all sorts of bookkeeping to get its state right. Transactions are not for performance, they are for keeping your system consistent.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I met a doctor who were thinking the same way. When I told him of my aches, he just told be what pills no take. No analysis, no examination. I have no idea if these pills will take any effect, as I still had no idea what is the reason for these aches. So I had to go to another clinic where they examined me all right and ordered the pills exactly to cure the right disease.

So it confirmed my fears that not only PHP users are using the same *modus operandi* - "let's take some action and see, if it helps".

However, this is wrong way to act. You need to examine your patient. To see what particular disease needs to be cured (*or if there is any disease at all*). Once you know it - then come ask for the pills to cure this very particular disease. As simple as that. Examine your application, find the bottleneck that makes it run slow (if any), and then ask how to solve this particular one.

Also, some things to let you know.

- you ought to always use prepared statements, no matter if you have any performance issues or not.
- prepared statements a **and** transactions can be used together all right, no need to change one for another.

Comment: Most of the time, a stern response drives the point home much better than a soft, fluffy and gentle one. This is why I like YCS' answers